# Why Id(IDENTITY) column starts with -1 in Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, datagridview

This is what I have done:

- Created a winforms project
- Added a service-based database with default settings
- Created a table and set the `Id` as `IDENTITY (1,1)`
- Created a datasource linked to the database
- Dragged and dropped the table as data gridview to the form
- Launched the project all I see is `Id` is set to `-1`

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's the default behavior of data set when created data table from database.  To change this behavior, you can go to the `DataSet` designer and select the key column of your `DataTable` and in properties, set `AutoIncrementSeed` and `AutoIncremenetStep` to `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in `DataGridView` is in fact generated using your `DataSet`. By default the data set uses `AutoIncrementSeed` and `AutoIncremenetStep` to `-1` for *Identity* columns generated from database.

To change this behavior, you can go to the `DataSet` designer and select the key column of your `DataTable` and in properties, set `AutoIncrementSeed` and `AutoIncremenetStep` to `1`

**Why dataset designer sets AutoIncrementSeed and AutoIncrementStep to -1?**

It tries to solve probable conflicts between dataset-generated identity values and database-generated identity values. To reproduce the problem which it's trying to solve:

1. Create a new and empty table with identity column (without trying to inset values in it).
2. Create DataSet designer from your database.
3. In `DataSet` designer, select the key column of your `DataTable` and set `AutoIncrementSeed` to `0` and `AutoIncremenetStep` to `1`.
4. Drag your table from *Data Source Window* and drop it on the form and run the program.
5. Enter 2 values and press save, you will get a `ConstraintException` exception:

   > Column 'Id' is constrained to be unique.  Value '1' is already
   >   present.